# ROSSERIAL and Helloworld issue on arduino 2560

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am quiet new to ubuntu and arduino. I managed to install arduino IDE, ROS and even ROSSERIAL.
Now while compiling (uploading) the hello world example I have a lot of errors and I don't know how to fix them.
Here I provided a printscreen of my IDE, terminal and also my home folders...maybe you can advise me something...

imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/screenshotfrom201303141.png/

P.S: my system information
Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz × 8
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
64bit

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58126/rosserial-and-helloworld-issue-on-arduino-2560/) by [Sasha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4423/sasha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-03-14**:
Did you load the example from the lib in the arduino interface? Looks like your library is not correctly installed..

**Comment by [Sasha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4423/sasha/) on 2013-03-14**:
Yes I used the example from ros_lib that I installed few hours ago. I took also a printscreen during my installation because I had an IOError (maybe that's why I have troubles). Any ideas how to fix it?    http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/screenshotfrom201303141.png/

**Comment by [Sasha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4423/sasha/) on 2013-03-14**:
Ok I figured out and fixed the problem thanks to my teacher! But there is definetly a bug with catkin and probably 64bits Ubuntu 12.04LTS. It would be nice if some developpers would find time to check it for the future...

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-03-14**:
Then please file a bug report (and also post your solution so that others can solve the problem also).

**Comment by [Sasha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4423/sasha/) on 2013-03-15**:
You need to edit your bashrc file by doing the next:   gedit gedit ~/.bashrc
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/alexander/catkin_ws/install/share:/home/alexander/catkin_ws/install/stacks:/home/alexander/catkin_ws:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution (for **ROS groovy and Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit**):

You need to edit your bashrc file by doing the next in terminal:  $gedit ~/.bashrc

After that you need to specify the path like this (just copy and paste somewhere inside):

*export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/YOURNAME_PROBABLY/catkin_ws/install/share:/home/YOURNAME_PROBABLY/catkin_ws/install/stacks:/home/YOURNAME_PROBABLY/catkin_ws:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH*

Info: catkin_ws is the catkin workspace that you should have settled up during ROS installation

After that I had also the problem while running:
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0

That USB0 should be ACM0 (for arduino)

That was it in short!

---

Originally posted by [Sasha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4423/sasha/) with karma: 16 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0